# How to change header format n bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am using bootstrap datepicker in my application.

Below is my code,

```
<div class='input-group date' id='dtpCalendar'>
<input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar">
        </span>
     </span>
</div>

$('#dtpCalendar').datepicker({
            startView: "months",
            Default: 'MMMM',
            format: 'mm/dd',
            multidate: true
});
```

Currently the datepicker looks like below,

[image: calendar header format]

I want to change the header format from MMMM YYYY to just MMMM.

I tried to change below code from bootstrap-datepicker.js but it doesn't work,

```
this.picker.find('#dtpCalendarthead .datepicker-switch')
                .text(DPGlobal.formatDate(new UTCDate(month), titleFormat, this.o.language));
```

What else can I try?

Comment: hmmm the question is Why ... what are you trying to do ... The year selector that comes with datepicker, does not it is useful to you ?

Comment: No. I just want month and day selectors. I want to hide year from everywhere.